# MySql server wont start

Tags: mysql

Sorry I'm completely out of my element in trying to set up MySQL to work on my machine. I'm running Windows 7 32x, and am not using WAMP or any other sort of server setup. I downloaded and installed everything off of the MySQL website with no issues, and during installation, I selected an option to start the server on startup. However the server is never running when I try to interact with it. If I go to the server startup/shutdown screen in MySQL Workbench and press the "start server" button, the server will start and run for a few seconds before shutting down due to causes I cannot figure out. After that, it says "The data service instance is unknown" and the "start server" button is now unclickable. The only messages I get are " Workbench will use cmd shell commands to start/stop this instance," and "Status check of service 'MySQL' returned error, see log." I've checked the server logs and they're completely empty. The only other logs I can think of are the System logs, which I'm not sure how to read. 
I don't know if this has anything to do with the problem, but I tried using the MySQL Server command line program, and anytime I put in the password (which I'm 100% sure is correct seeing as I just set it to "password" and was going to change it later), some sort of message comes up, but the window closes too fast for me to read it.
Please keep in mind I'm very new to this field and it's very likely that I made an incredibly simple mistake. Here is part of the error log that I think pertains to this issue.

```
2013-12-16 19:55:49 1324 [Note] Event Scheduler: Loaded 0 events
2013-12-16 19:55:49 1324 [Note] C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\bin\mysqld:ready for connections.
Version: '5.6.15'  socket: ''  port: 0  MySQL Community Server (GPL)
2013-12-16 19:55:49 1324 [ERROR] TCP/IP, --shared-memory, or --named-pipe should be configured on NT OS
2013-12-16 19:55:49 1324 [ERROR] Aborting

2013-12-16 19:55:49 1324 [Note] Binlog end
2013-12-16 19:55:49 1324 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'partition'
(etc... shuts down more plugins...)
```

Comment: Are you using the command line from a command prompt ? If not, try so by running `cmd.exe` in Windows menu, and try the command again, it should not close the window on errors.

Comment: http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=64826

looks similar to yours. Have you tried re-installing everything in a clean path?

Comment: I tried to use the MySQL command line client through cmd.exe but wasn't able to connect. Not sure if the server has to already be running to be able to use cmd to access MySQL or not.

Comment: I found where the log is and I think I found the part that has to do with the server starting and stopping itself. I'll edit in to my question.

Answer (score 0):

Just found in your log that mysql daemon started on port 0. Port 0 is reserved.

Ideas:

- Check if port 3306 is free. It's standard one for mysql.
- Check "skip-networking" and "port" options in my.cfg